# google contextual gadget not loading google app script first time > Need to implement Authorization flow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I have google contextual gagdet installed in my domain, and that contextual; gadget is fetching data from external google App script whose url is something like this :
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzP2A1SlTFxXVy39b5KmvNLFDSTeDveR49od-Wno2VFdcdT9m0/exec

I am calling this script from google contextual gadget using following jsonp ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: app_script_url,
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

but when my gadget is loaded after opening any email, I seem following error in my console log:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
<html><head><title>Authorization needed</title><style>.auth-
```

So basically what I want is, When loading the gadget in my gmail message when first time gadget is loaded and if user do not have authorization access, then it should ask use to authorize the script using some button or link, Similar to what is shown when you click on this link > https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzP2A1SlTFxXVy39b5KmvNLFDSTeDveR49od-Wno2VFdcdT9m0/exec

Till now I have tried many approaches like I tried the approach from this link

```
https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/oauth
```

I tried the example shown in this link, I replaced url shown in fetchData() function with the above one, but I was not sure what oAuth parameters to use. so in a way I am now stuck to implement authorization flow.

Let me know if anyone has any idea on this.

Thanks in advance!!
Dean

Answer (score 0):

Your link about 'gadgets' has nothing to do with apps script its a completely different thing called google gadgets (from igoogle).
Your problem is likely that you havent published the gas correctly. Either publish it as anonymous access or make the ajax call authenticated. In any case do not publish the script to run as the user accesing the script.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, the code above is present inside gmail contextual gadget and this gadget code is calling external google app script. So gadget is loaded first time when opening an email, then at that time it tries to call the google app script(mentioned in the post), so in a way a user first manually has to go to that script and get him / her self authenticated first..'

But I need some mechanism in which user should get some auth button or link inside gmail contextuals gadget itself so that user do not have to manually go that app script and get themse authenticated

Comment: yes, i know its inside a contextual gadget, but the oauth there cant be used for the apps script. Why does the apps script need authentication for each user? Are you publishing the script to run "As the user accessing the app"? if so you cant avoid skipping that first authentication that gas asks for. if you must run it as the user, you could make a dummy ajax authenticated call to the gas and detect it failed, then show your authorization button which will open a new tab with the same gas with some parameter so you know it comes from there. In there the user will see the gas auth popups.

Comment: I have deployed my gas as Anonymouse user rights, but gadget is still not loading it is waiting for the authorization(I am not sure this is a bug or so).

Also I tried with dummy call to the script using $.ajax mehtod with datatype as jsonp , but call is triggering and I am not getting any response instead in firefox console I am getting the error which i have posted above in my post..So even if I can get a way using which I can atleast get the response of script failure I can show the link...But here the prob is I m not able to test it using dummy ajax call

Comment: what happens when you just enter to that URL in the browser?

Comment: When I am entering that gas url in the browser it is giving me Authorize button to authorize the gas.. until I have not authorize the script by manually going in the browser it does not load inside gadget.

So similarly if I can get a way by which user should see a url in the gagdet(if auth is required) otherwise it is automatically calling the gas

Comment: you still havent said how its published, as the user accesing the script or as the owner?

Comment: It is published as user accessing the script..BTW I have tried publishing in both the ways, but still script needs to get authorized on first visit

Comment: if you publish it to run as the owner, then you should authorize it first. then it will work for any user. Of course it depends what your gas does. if it accesses user data you will need to run it as the user.